# MySQL, select, comparing values from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, database, select, compare, heidisql

in my [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIIy9.png) I want to select every construction_manual

`where storage_room.quantity > component.quantity`

But when I use:

```
SELECT construction_manual.name
FROM construction_manual cm, construction_manual_component cmc, component, storage_room
WHERE cm.ID = cmc.construction_manual_ID
AND cmc.component_ID = component.ID
AND component.storage_room_ID = storage_room.ID
AND storage_room.quantity > component.quantity
```

It will select every construction_manual.name as long as the first component in the storage_room has enough quantity.
So let's say...

`construction_manual.1 needs`

```
component.A -> quantity 5 
component.B -> quantity 10
```

and in the storage room there is:

```
component.A -> quantity 6
component.B -> quantity 0
```

Although there is not enough in the storage room, `construction_manual.1` will be selected. How do I select only those `construction_manuals` where there are enough components in the storage_room?

---

edit:

In my 4 tables are the following datasets. I will get the following result when I use the query mentioned above:[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jR57K.png) . But I should not be able to construct a table because there are not enough wooden_plates (wooden planks and not wooden plates ofc...ups)

---

Comment: plz provide little more data so that it can be easy to write any query

Comment: You have 50 screws in storage.  That is greater than the quantity in component (10).  Screws (component_ID: 3) is in both the manuals for chair (1) and table (2) and thus the results will show both construction manuals.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to ask is to **ignore or exclude** any construction manual that does not have enough components to satisfy a build.  If that's the case you can do something like the below (a left join would also do it):

```
select distinct cm.name as construction_manual
  from construction_manual cm
  join construction_manual_component cmc
    on cmc.construction_manual_ID = cm.ID
  join component c
    on c.ID = cmc.component_ID
  join storage_room sr
    on sr.ID = c.storage_room_ID
 where sr.quantity > c.quantity
   and cm.ID not in (select cm.ID
                       from construction_manual cm
                       join construction_manual_component cmc
                         on cmc.construction_manual_ID = cm.ID
                       join component c
                         on c.ID = cmc.component_ID
                       join storage_room sr
                         on sr.ID = c.storage_room_ID
                      where sr.quantity < c.quantity);
```